# Converting Expression<Func<T,object>> to string

Tags: c#, lambda, linq-expressions

I try to convert an expression in the form `Expression<Func<Person,object>>` to a string for later manipulation.

This expression is stored in a property in a class and it's used in source code generation.

Example 1 (This works as expected)

```
Expression<Func<Person,object>> exp1 = p => "abc";  
Console.WriteLine(exp1.ToString() ); // ok, p => "abc"
```

Example 2 (This has a result that is not expected):

```
Expression<Func<Person,object>> exp2 = p =>  Guid.NewGuid();
Console.WriteLine(exp2.ToString()); 
//the string is including a convert method:  p => Convert(NewGuid(), Object)
```

I expect expression to be `p =>  Guid.NewGuid()`, without including the `Convert` method: `f=> Convert(NewGuid(), Object)`

The problem in  the `Convert` method is the string expression is un usable and cause  a compilation error in the new source code generated.

What do I need to do to get the expression as is: `f =>  Guid.NewGuid()` without a Convert method?

Demo for a [test case](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mwbpXk)

Comment: well, a `Guid` is a value-type, whereas your delegate returns an `object` - a reference-type. So you have to box the guid into an object. The compiler just automatically does this transformation for you, however. You could also use `exp2 = p =>  (object) Guid.NewGuid();`, which is what the compiler does as well. That's just for **why** you get that result, though.

Comment: ^^ Which is true, but I think, OP wants something different. As I understand, he wants the `p => something` part as string. Am I right, M.?

Comment: why should your delegate return `object` in the first place?

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain, Thanks, I cast the expression as object, and Compiler still return string with Convert method, see my [test case](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mwbpXk). I use delegate that return object, because expression return different data types: string, int, double,Guid,..

Comment: Sure it does. I just mentioned, this is what compiler does internally anyway, to clearify *why* you have that additional convert.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain, I reuse the string expression for source Code generation.

Comment: @M.Hassan: Use an ExpressionVisitor to discover the structure of the Expression.  The "stringification" is meant only for inclusion in log messages, and cannot be trusted to be valid C# code.  In particular, in your example `ToString()` spits out VB.NET code, not C# code... because all .NET languages share the same implementation of `Expression`, it's not possible to have different string results depending on the original source language used.

Answer (score 2):

By using Generics you might get what you're looking for.

Here's a snippet.

```
    public static void Main()
    {
         var text1 = GetExpressionText(x => "abc");
         Console.WriteLine(text1);
         var text2 = GetExpressionText(x => Guid.NewGuid());
         Console.WriteLine(text2);
    }
    
    private static string GetExpressionText<TReturn>(Expression<Func<Person, TReturn>> expression) {
        return expression.ToString();
    }
```

[A fiddle so you can do some more testing.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9lQceZ)

Comment: Thanks for answer, Try to pass a variable to 'GetExpressionText`, you still get Convert method :). see my example using [your implementation](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nCzdpA)

Comment: Hmm... Except you don't get the Convert on my implementation. Of course, if you specify an Expression<Func<Person, object>> and then pass it to GetExpressionText, then you'll still get the same behaviour, because nothing changed and you're not really using generics. What your first invocation of the method is basically doing under the hood is "(object)Guid.NewGuid()". That will ALWAYS create a convertion on the expression tree. That doesn't happen with string cause strings are reference types. Guid, double, int and other value types and will get the same behavior.